# Can't load images to a HTML5 canvas in PhoneGap Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to draw an image to the screen using canvas, when I do it I get: '`Your browser does not support the canvas element.`'.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image()
    img.src = "img_flwr.png";
    img.onload = function () {
        cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
</script>
```

After a bit of research I found nothing about the compatablilty of canvas in PhoneGap's webview so I guess that there is no problem and the problem is here only.

I am looking forward to make a map with navigation functionality like path finding etc., if there is another way (easier maybe)that would be great too.

Thanks in Advance

p.s - this is a code sample not my code

Update:
The problem is mostly that i try on the Emulator not and actual Window phone, i tried it on my Android phone and it worked perfectly, and since phonegap is not platform specific i think it will be the same for the windows phone.
will try it on an actual windows phone and update the post

thanks to everyone that helped

Comment: The canvas tag isn't supported by your phone.

Comment: Sounds like the browser you use does not support the canvas element. Which one is it? IE 8? Also you should move `img.src = "img_flwr.png";` below the `img.onload = function ...` as in some occasions it will not fire the onload when you set src before.

Comment: Can it be cause am using the emulator? the WindowsPhone 8 emulator

Comment: As Windows Phone 8 ships with IE 10, which has canvas support, it could be. Isn't there some menu option to show browser version?

Comment: The problem is with the Emulator, it doesn't support Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas element is supported both by the device and in the current emulators for the Windows Phone. I just retested it in a very simple example, and the canvas content is displayed.

If the web page with the `canvas` element does not have the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

it may not work. You could output the value of `document.documentMode` to further troubleshoot if necessary.